# Service worker basic setup

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

I have the following code for a service worker:

```
'use strict';

// Incrementing CACHE_VERSION will kick off the install event and force previously cached
// resources to be cached again.
const CACHE_VERSION = 1;
let CURRENT_CACHES = {
    offline: 'offline-v' + CACHE_VERSION
};
const OFFLINE_URL = 'offline.php';

function createCacheBustedRequest(url) {
    let request = new Request(url, {cache: 'reload'});
    // See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-mode
    // This is not yet supported in Chrome as of M48, so we need to explicitly check to see
    // if the cache: 'reload' option had any effect.
    if ('cache' in request) {
        return request;
    }

    // If {cache: 'reload'} didn't have any effect, append a cache-busting URL parameter instead.
    let bustedUrl = new URL(url, self.location.href);
    bustedUrl.search += (bustedUrl.search ? '&' : '') + 'cachebust=' + Date.now();
    return new Request(bustedUrl);
}

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        // We can't use cache.add() here, since we want OFFLINE_URL to be the cache key, but
        // the actual URL we end up requesting might include a cache-busting parameter.
        fetch(createCacheBustedRequest(OFFLINE_URL)).then(function(response) {
            return caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES.offline).then(function(cache) {
                return cache.put(OFFLINE_URL, response);
            });
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    // Delete all caches that aren't named in CURRENT_CACHES.
    // While there is only one cache in this example, the same logic will handle the case where
    // there are multiple versioned caches.
    let expectedCacheNames = Object.keys(CURRENT_CACHES).map(function(key) {
        return CURRENT_CACHES[key];
    });

event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
        return Promise.all(
            cacheNames.map(cacheName => {
                if (expectedCacheNames.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
    // If this cache name isn't present in the array of "expected" cache names,
    // then delete it.
    console.log('Deleting out of date cache:', cacheName);
    return caches.delete(cacheName);
}
})
);
})
);
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    // We only want to call event.respondWith() if this is a navigation request
    // for an HTML page.
    // request.mode of 'navigate' is unfortunately not supported in Chrome
    // versions older than 49, so we need to include a less precise fallback,
    // which checks for a GET request with an Accept: text/html header.
    if (event.request.mode === 'navigate' ||
        (event.request.method === 'GET' &&
            event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html'))) {
    console.log('Handling fetch event for', event.request.url);
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(createCacheBustedRequest(event.request.url)).catch(error => {
            // The catch is only triggered if fetch() throws an exception, which will most likely
            // happen due to the server being unreachable.
            // If fetch() returns a valid HTTP response with an response code in the 4xx or 5xx
            // range, the catch() will NOT be called. If you need custom handling for 4xx or 5xx
            // errors, see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/service-worker/fallback-response
            console.log('Fetch failed; returning offline page instead.', error);
    return caches.match(OFFLINE_URL);
})
);
}

// If our if() condition is false, then this fetch handler won't intercept the request.
// If there are any other fetch handlers registered, they will get a chance to call
// event.respondWith(). If no fetch handlers call event.respondWith(), the request will be
// handled by the browser as if there were no service worker involvement.
});
```

How could it be possible to make it in a way so that it does not have to save anything on cache? The webapp in question needs connection at all time. Therefore, the main purpose of this service worker is to qualify for phone installation and to have later on push notifications capabilities.

Comment: Can't you just, you know, remove the lines where you're saving it to the cache?

Comment: the problem is that those first lines have variables used all through the code, so I was wondering what would be the basic minimum that could still fit for the development of push notifications later.

Comment: `cache.put(OFFLINE_URL, response);` That's saving things to the cache. Experiment with removing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some online research, here is the best solution:

sw_install.js

```
    console.log('Started', self);
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    self.skipWaiting();
    console.log('Installed', event);
});
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    console.log('Activated', event);
});
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    console.log('Push message received', event);
    // TODO
});
```

main.js

```
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log('Service Worker is supported');
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw_install.js').then(function(reg){
        console.log(':^)', reg);
        // TODO
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(':^(', err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use npm sw-toolbox library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sw-toolbox).

**main.js**

```html
if (navigator.serviceWorker){
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', {scope: './'})
        .then(function (registration) {
            console.log("sw registered",registration);
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.error("error",e);
        })
    } else {
        console.log('Service Worker is not supported in this browser.')
    }
}
```

**service-worker.js**

```js
(global => {
  'use strict';
  // Load the sw-tookbox library.
  importScripts('/js/sw-toolbox.js');

  var precache_urls = [
      '/index.html',
      '/img/logo.png',
      '/img/main.png'
  ];

  //for debugging only
  global.toolbox.options.debug = true;

  global.toolbox.router.get('/img/(.*)', self.toolbox.cacheFirst, {
  cache: {
    name: "Images",
    maxEntries: 10
    }
  });
  global.toolbox.router.default = global.toolbox.networkFirst;

  global.addEventListener('install', event => event.waitUntil(global.skipWaiting()));
  global.addEventListener('activate', event => event.waitUntil(global.clients.claim()));
  global.addEventListener('push', event => {
    var pushObj = event.data.json();
    var pushData = pushObj.data;

    // push payload if there, if not make an ajax get call to get it (can use fetch)
    var title = pushData && pushData.title;
    var body = pushData && pushData.body;
    var icon = '/img/logo.png';
                event.waitUntil(global.registration.showNotification(title, {
                body: body,
                icon: icon,
                badge: icon
                data:pushData
            }));

         });
  global.addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
    event.notification.close();
    var url = event.notification.data.url|| '/';
    event.waitUntil(
      clients.matchAll({
        type: 'window'
      }).then(windowClients => {
        console.log('WindowClients', windowClients);
        for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
          var client = windowClients[i];
          console.log('WindowClient', client);
          if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
            return client.focus();
          }
       }
       if (clients.openWindow) {
         return clients.openWindow(url);
       }
    }));
  });
})(self);
```